# Accessing object methods from in a list

Tags: r, list, object

a bit new to R and I'm having some trouble accessing objects I've placed in a list.

I create my objects in a list like this:

```
myObjects <- vector("list", P)
for(i in 1:10){
  myObjects[[i]] <- new.myObject()
}
```

Then I want to access some methods I've created in the code, so I got to access them like this:

```
myObjects[1]@myMethod
```

However, when I do that I get the error:
Error: trying to get slot "myMethod" from an object of a basic class ("list") with no slots

When I just have 1 object my code works fine, but after I've put it into a list I'm not sure how to get it back out of the list. I get that R deals with things as 'lists of size 1' a lot of the time, but it isn't working for me here. Is there a way to just get the object out of the list rather than a list of size 1 containing my object?

Comment: Have a look at Hadley's material on subsetting here http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

Comment: You are not showing any use of `setClass()` which would be expected for building an S4-object. Unlike some languages there is not a built-in `new` operation. You cannot just assume that R acts like your favorite OOP language.

Comment: @DWin: I have all of that setup elsewhere. As I mentioned my code was working with 1 object but not in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[` operator gives you a sublist: `myObjects[1]` is a list of length one.

`[[` is the operator to get a list item: `myObjects[[1]]` is the first item in your list.

So `myObjects[[1]]@myMethod` is what should work here.

Comment: Sheesh, much simpler than I thought, 100% fixed my problem. I did know this at one point, I guess it just slipped my mind. At least I knew it was an issue with a list of length one vs just the object I guess.